# virtualenv name not show in zsh prompt

Tags: bash, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Recently, I give a try on oh my zsh, everything looks good till I try virtualevn and virtualenvwrapper. When I activate a virtualenv (e.g test), on normal bash, I will see the virtualenv name like:

```
(test)abc@abc:
```

But when I switched to zsh, I cannot see virtualenv name. Even though, I alr add virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper in plugins of oh my zsh. I also checked the activate file of my virtualenv, it contains:

```
f [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT-}" ] ; then        
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
    if [ "x" != x ] ; then
        PS1="$PS1"
    else
        PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`) $PS1"
    fi
        export PS1
fi
```

Is it because the comparision ["x" != x] return true?

**Updated:**
I tried to echo $PS1 in activate file, and got this:

```
(test) %{$fg[magenta]%}%n%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[cyan]%}@%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[yellow]%}%m%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[red]%}:%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[cyan]%}%0~%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[red]%}|%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[cyan]%}⇒%{$reset_color%}
```

It seems the $PS1 is correct, but when I echo $PS1 in the terminal, the (test) is gone. It seems the $PS1 is override by something else!

Comment: `[ "x" != x ]` always returns _false_; it compares literal `x` against itself.

Comment: then, why the basename not prepend to $PS1?

Comment: Does the prompt start with `()`? Note that you needn't `\ `-escape the `"` chars. in  `\"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"` (though it shouldn't hurt).

Comment: How come it works fine with bash, but fails with zsh? Is there any different on sh syntax between these two?

Comment: With the code you're showing us, I wouldn't expect there to be a difference. Can you pare it down to a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include the exact symptoms?

Comment: I am using mac os, what i did is install oh my zsh, and then the virtualenv name disappear when using zsh. I also have no idea why! Not sure u got this issue before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120844/discussion-between-bent-and-mklement0).

Comment: I assumed to have the virtualenv promt on the left side. But it was on the left side. I think I configured it once but forgot it. Took me 15 minutes to figure it out, as I was focused on the left side...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the problem, it's due to the theme. The theme I used in the above case is pygmalion, it won't allow u to change $PS1.

After changed to robbyrussell theme, I can change $PS1 in terminal, but still cannot see the virtualenv name. After a while debugging, I found that by default the virtualenv plugin of oh my zsh disable the prompt:

```
# disables prompt mangling in virtual_env/bin/activate
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
```

So just comment out the line in virtualenv plugin, problem solved.

Comment: it's not working, I've commented out this, and added to the plugins, but, still not working. :(

Comment: I cannot find VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT. Even by setting VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=0 under theme robbyrussel it's not working.

Comment: hey, that's odd. But do you want to give a try with @Greg suggestion?

Comment: FYI, 6 years later, another solution to this is to add `virtualenv` to your plugins and change your theme to `pygmalion-virtualenv`.

Answer (score 105):

Do this in `~/.zshrc`:

```
plugins=(virtualenv)

POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status virtualenv)
```

Caveats:

1 -- add that plugin in addition to other plugins you have.

2 -- I'm using the POWERLEVEL9K theme. Maybe you theme

Comment: This was a very succinct answer that suited my situation as I too am using the same theme. The environment will show on the right side of the screen.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work even when I only use the virtualenv plugin.

Comment: `POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status root_indicator background_jobs history time virtualenv)` gave me what I was looking for. Thanks William.

Comment: @ArunDas comment helped me by not removing the existing data on screen.

Comment: I'm using `trapd00r` theme and this method didn't work for me.

Answer (score 46):

The best solution is to add the following to the end of your ~/.zshrc file:

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=
```

This will override the value in virtualenv.plugin.zsh - no need to change that file.

Comment: I had to use `export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=0`

Comment: To be more specific, I had to place it after the `source ${ZSH}/oh-my-zsh.sh` line. Also setting it to any value (`0` or `1`) as suggested in other answers didn't work for me. I am using Urxvt and powerlevel9k.

Comment: `export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=` after the `source ${ZSH}/oh-my-zsh.sh` line works fine for theme `amuse`

Answer (score 31):

My setting to display Python virtualenv name for the default (a.k.a. `robbyrussell`) theme is the following.

**In the `.zshrc` file**

1. `virtualenv` added in `plugins`
2. Add custom function:

   ```
   function virtualenv_info { 
       [ $VIRTUAL_ENV ] && echo '('`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`') '
   }
   ```

**Navigate to your theme**

3. My theme is the default theme for `zsh`:

   ```
   $ vim ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme
   ```
4. Add this command right after existing `PROMPT` commands:

   ```
   PROMPT+='%{$fg[green]%}$(virtualenv_info)%{$reset_color%}%'
   ```

**Finally**

```
$ source ~/.zshrc
```

**PS:** You can add your name or a few space before or after the PROMPT+.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The function you create is `virtualenv_info` but then in the prompt it is `virtualenv_prompt_info` is that intended ?

Comment: @Davos No, it was a typo. Check the updated answer.

Comment: The only answer which worked for me. I'm using `trapd00r` theme. +1

Comment: Wow thank you. That was VERY helpful and fixed my issue. I made a slight modification and just modified `PROMPT+=` in `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/robbyrussell.zsh-theme` to simply

`PROMPT+='%{$fg[green]%}$(virtualenv_info)%{$reset_color%}%{$fg[cyan]%}%c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info)'`

(I like the virtualenv to be first on the far left of the prompt)

Comment: Works like a charm! Just leaving this updated function here for people that would like to show the actual python version used:         ``` function virtualenv_info { 
    [ $VIRTUAL_ENV ] && echo '('`$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/python --version | sed 's,Python ,,'`') '
}```

Answer (score 8):

As per this guide [here](https://ohadp.com/print-your-current-virtualenv-name-in-your-zsh-theme-in-30-secs-1efee5a2d628)

- First add `virtualenv` dependency under `plugin` in file `.zshrc`
  If this doesn't work for you, then it means that the theme(one of oh-my-zsh theme) you have selected doesn't include virtualenv name in bash prompt so try second step.
- Go to file `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/YOUR_THEME_NAME.zsh-theme` and add this in  base prompt

  `%{$fg[green]%}$(virtualenv_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}%`

**NOTE**: `virtualenv_prompt_info` is the name of function which is declared in `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/virtualenv/virtualenv.plugin.zsh`. If your plugin file have different function name then change it accordingly.

Or you can declare your own function in `~/.zshrc` file as shown in this [guide](https://ohadp.com/print-your-current-virtualenv-name-in-your-zsh-theme-in-30-secs-1efee5a2d628)

Comment: In my case theme `robbyrussell` did not work. So I added this (along side others)
PROMPT+=' $(virtualenv_prompt_info)'  works fine now

Answer (score 5):

If you are using conda to start your virtual environment the envorionment variable will be different. To figure out the name of the environment that holds your virtaulenv name type `printenv` and look through the output. For me it is `CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER`

after you know the name of the variable open .zshrc and add this function

`` function virtualenv_info {
 [ $CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER ] && echo `basename $CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER`
} ``

and below that add this line

`PROMPT="%{$fg[green]%}$(virtualenv_info)%{$reset_color%}%${PROMPT}"`

close the editor and type `source .zshrc`

Answer (score 5):

In the case you installed Anaconda using Homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/cask-versions 
brew cask install anaconda
```

And you are using POWERLEVEL9K theme

```
git clone https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k.git ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes/powerlevel9k
```

All you need to do is add this line to the end of .zshrc :

```
POWERLEVEL9K_RIGHT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(status root_indicator background_jobs history time anaconda)
```

There's no need for virtualenv plugin.

Edited:

In case you already had conda installed for bash and you get:

```
zsh: command not found: conda
```

Run this:

```
~/anaconda3/bin/conda init zsh
```

Answer (score 3):

I am also using Oh My Zsh with the pygmalion theme. I had to edit the pygmalion script to add the virtual environment name before the prompt name.

- open `~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/pygmalion.zsh-theme`, modify the `prompt_pygmalion_precmd` function as following:

```
prompt_pygmalion_precmd(){
  setopt localoptions extendedglob

  local gitinfo=$(git_prompt_info)
  local gitinfo_nocolor=${gitinfo//\%\{[^\}]##\}}
  local exp_nocolor="$(print -P \"$base_prompt_nocolor$gitinfo_nocolor$post_prompt_nocolor\")"
  local prompt_length=${#exp_nocolor}
  local python_venv="($(echo $CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV)) "

  PROMPT="${python_venv}${base_prompt}${gitinfo}${post_prompt}"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! there is also this version here: https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/themes/pygmalion-virtualenv.zsh-theme

Answer (score 1):

I made it work following this link: https://askubuntu.com/a/387098

I reproduce the answer below.

How the prompt is changed is defined in the script `bin/activate` inside the virtual environment directory. This file is created by `virtualenv` from a template. Unfortunatelly, the only way of prompt modification provided by the template is prepending `(env name)` or whatever is set with `--prompt`.

To modify the prompt in the way you want, I'd suggest circumventing the setting of the prompt in `bin/activate` and modify the definition of `PROMPT` in your theme file.

First add the following to your`.zsh-theme` (or `.zshrc`)

```
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=yes

function virtenv_indicator {
    if [[ -z $VIRTUAL_ENV ]] then
        psvar[1]=''
    else
        psvar[1]=${VIRTUAL_ENV##*/}
    fi
}

add-zsh-hook precmd virtenv_indicator
```

and add `%(1V.(%1v).)` in front of the second line of the definition of `PROMPT`. It should then look like this:

```
PROMPT='
%(1V.(%1v).)%{$fg_bold[grey]%}[%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[${host_color}]%}%n@%m%{$reset_color%}%{$fg_bold[grey]%}]%{$reset_color%} %{$fg_bold[blue]%}%10c%{$reset_color%} $(git_prompt_info) $(git_remote_status)
%{$fg_bold[cyan]%}❯%{$reset_color%} '
```

If you want some color you could add `%(1V.%{$fs_bold[yellow]%}(%1v)%{$reset_color%}.)` for example.

**Explanation**:

`virtenv_indicator` will be called each time before the prompt is created. It checks if `$VIRTUAL_ENV` is set and not empty. If so, it sets the first element of the `$psvar` array to `$VIRTUAL_ENV` with everything before and including the last `/` removed (like `basename $VIRTUAL_ENV` but less expensive)

In the definition of `PROMPT` `%(1V.(%1v).)` checks if the first element of `$psvar` is set and not empty (`%(1V.true-text.false-text)`) and adds the content of the this element plus some parentheses (`(%1v)`)

`export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=yes` disables any prompt setting by `bin/activate` scripts.

Answer (score 1):

if you use zsh and pyenv, put this into ~/.zshrc

```
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
#export PS1='($(pyenv version-name)) '$PS1

export PYENV_VIRTUALENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
export BASE_PROMPT=$PS1
function updatePrompt {
    if [[ "$(pyenv version-name)" != "system" ]]; then
        # the next line should be double quote; single quote would not work for me
        export PS1="($(pyenv version-name)) "$BASE_PROMPT
    else
        export PS1=$BASE_PROMPT
    fi
}
export PROMPT_COMMAND='updatePrompt'
precmd() { eval '$PROMPT_COMMAND' } # this line is necessary for zsh
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create new function, as per documentation - this function is created for you.
[https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/virtualenv](http://documentation)

But You still need to edit theme file, as mentioned above, *just enter correct function name - virtualenv_prompt_info*:

PROMPT+='%{$fg[green]%}$(virtualenv_prompt_info)%{$reset_color%}%'

Answer (score 1):

```
export PS1='($(pyenv version-name)) '$PS1
```

source & link to issue #135 in pyenv-virtualenv repo:

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv-virtualenv/issues/135#issuecomment-582180662

Answer (score 1):

The following steps should solve the problem:

1. open `~/.p10k.zsh`.
2. If you use only the **left prompt**, make the following changes:

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_LEFT_PROMPT_ELEMENTS=(
    # =========================[ Line #1 ]=========================
    os_icon                    # os identifier
    dir                        # current directory
    vcs                        # git status
    # =========================[ Line #2 ]=========================
    newline                    # \n
    prompt_char                # prompt symbol
    virtualenv venv .venv env  # show the venv on the second line
  )
```

3. Add the following line, preferably after you adjust `POWERLEVEL9K_VIRTUALENV_SHOW_WITH_PYENV`:

```
  typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_VIRTUALENV_GENERIC_NAMES=()
```

4. Save the `.p10k.zsh`.
5. Restart the terminal.

Now, when you activate the virtual environment (on macOS `source my_venv/bin/activate`), then the name of the virtual environment (in my case, `my_venv`) and the version of Python installed on it (`3.9.13`) will appear after a beautiful Python symbol. Have a look at the attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlKJ7.png).

Answer (score 0):

I am using oh-my-zsh pygmalion them, and this works for me:

- add `virtualenv` plugin in ~/.zshrc
- open ~/.oh-my-zsh/themes/pygmalion.zsh-theme, modify the `prompt_pygmalion_precmd` function to this:

  ```
   prompt_pygmalion_precmd(){
     setopt localoptions extendedglob

     local gitinfo=$(git_prompt_info)
     local gitinfo_nocolor=${gitinfo//\%\{[^\}]##\}}
     local exp_nocolor="$(print -P \"$base_prompt_nocolor$gitinfo_nocolor$post_prompt_nocolor\")"
     local prompt_length=${#exp_nocolor}
     local python_venv=$(virtualenv_prompt_info)

     PROMPT="${python_venv}${base_prompt}${gitinfo}${post_prompt}"
   }
  ```

Basically just add `$(virtualenv_prompt_info)` to your `PROMPT` to wherever you prefer, here I added it to the very beginning of my PROMPT.

Answer (score 0):

After playing with the surround answers, I found the following to be the best for my use case. This checks the $VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT and $VIRTUAL_ENV variables every time you change directories and sets the prompt with the correct venv info.

```
DEFAULT_PROMPT=$PROMPT

function cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"

  if [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT" ]] ; then
      PROMPT="$VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT$DEFAULT_PROMPT"
  elif [[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]] ; then
      PROMPT="(`basename $VIRTUAL_ENV`) $DEFAULT_PROMPT"
  else
      PROMPT=$DEFAULT_PROMPT
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Back to 2023 : here something that worked for me with the theme .
Search the line for "plugins" and add virtualenv (if you are using this one)

```
plugins=(git python brew macos colored-man-pages virtualenv vscode)
```

Now look for the ZSH-Theme and use

```
ZSH_THEME="pygmalion-virtualenv"
```

Reload your terminal or kill your Visual Studio code window (reloading the terminal into VS cod didn't display the change for me...)

Answer (score 0):

For those using MacOS with [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) and the [powerlevel10k](https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k) theme,
to display the python version along with the activated virtual environment,
I had to:

1. Open the `~/.p10k.zsh` file
2. Search and Set in **true** the variable `typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_VIRTUALENV_SHOW_WITH_PYENV=true`
3. Save the file and Apply the changes with `source ~/.p10k.zsh`

*Note: No extra plugins are needed as `virtualenv` is already activated by default inside the `~/.p10k.zsh` file*

This is how it looks:

[python and venv prompts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKCqX.jpg)