# Showing virtualenv in zsh

Tags: python, virtualenv, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm in the process of switching from bash to zsh, and I'm having trouble getting Python virtual environment info to display correctly in my prompt. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38928717/virtualenv-name-not-show-in-zsh-prompt) has the most detail, but many of the answers are referring to specific themes, and I'm trying to do it manually.

I copied and slightly modified code from `oh-my-zsh` and from that thread; here's what I have in my `.zshrc`:

```
function virtualenv_prompt_info(){
  [[ -n ${VIRTUAL_ENV} ]] || return
  echo "${ZSH_THEME_VIRTUALENV_PREFIX=[}${VIRTUAL_ENV:t:gs/%/%%}${ZSH_THEME_VIRTUALENV_SUFFIX=]} "
}

# disables prompt mangling in virtual_env/bin/activate
export VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1

# add virtualenv to prompt
ZSH_THEME_VIRTUALENV_PREFIX='('
ZSH_THEME_VIRTUALENV_SUFFIX=')'
PROMPT='$(virtualenv_prompt_info)'

# (not shown: other additions to the prompt that occur later)
```

The result of this is that when I am in zsh, in a directory under a virtual environment, and execute `source venv/bin/activate`, I then get a `(venv)`  at the start of my prompt, as I desire. However, there are two problems: When I leave the directory that has the virtualenv, that `(venv)`  prefix remains in my prompt; and when I enter a directory with a live virtualenv, I don't get the prefix unless I re-run `activate`. The behavior I desire is that I get the prefix any time I'm in a directory where a virtual environment is active (without having to do anything manually), and I don't get the prefix if I'm not in such a directory.

These both worked correctly with the prompt mangling that's built in to virtualenv, but I'd like to control it with zsh (I may start using a theme later, but for now I want to control everything manually). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the virtual env isn't being loaded when you enter into a new one? (ie, are you only relying on visual feedback in the prompt, or are you verifying with `which python` when inside / outside the various venv environment folders) I didn't actually know that this was possible, from my understanding the virtual env needs to be run with `path/to/env/bin/activate`, and deactivated with `deactivate`

Have you also tried to do this without your custom code? i.e. keeping `VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT` unset, so that the default behaviour of venv is maintained?

Answer (score 0):

[[ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]]

You should be checking the length of the string so you need quotes